# Spring boot classpath file not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

All we have an XML file we want to load when start a spring boot app. We run it with the following command:

```
java -DProfileId=default -Dloader.path=`pwd` -jar app.jar
```

But this then throws

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [default-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Event tho the config file exists in that directory

Comment: in which directory does it exists?

Comment: In the same lib / directory as app.jar

Comment: it should be in your resources folder of project. Do read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Not sure I understand. The app is just a jar and an xml configuration file within a folder on Unix. What resources directory?

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts on this?